# Very very slow query. How can I improve it?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

the following query is used in my Wordpress blog, it gets the categories that a user has posted in. When he has a post in the category, the name of the category is shown.

It is a very very slow query because it is a big database and I have problems with the hosting company.

I have 3 categories, with id 3 called News, 4 called Articles and 5 called Others. My code is:

```
<?php
$author = get_query_var('author');
$categories = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT DISTINCT(terms.term_id) as ID, terms.name, terms.slug, tax.description
    FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as relationships ON posts.ID = relationships.object_ID
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tax ON relationships.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as terms ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id
    WHERE 1=1 AND (
        posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
        posts.post_author = '{$post->post_author}' AND
        tax.taxonomy = 'category' )
    ORDER BY terms.term_id ASC
");
?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
<?php if ( ($category->ID == '3')   || ($category->ID == '4')  || ($category->ID == '5')) { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->ID ); ?>/?author_name=<?php echo $curuser->user_login; ?>" title="<?php echo $category->name ?>">
            <?php echo $category->name; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the looks of the wordpress database I have lying around, I'm guessing there is no index on the columns you are using in your `WHERE` clause for the `wp_posts` table.

Try adding an index like this:

`ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD INDEX (post_author,post_status)`.

I bet you see a speed up from that.

The best thing to do however is to run that query manually with an `EXPLAIN` in front of the `SELECT`, and [analyze the output](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html).

Comment: What does the INDEX will do ?

Comment: Indexes are a basic feature of databases.  There is a lot to learn about them, more than can be covered in a Stack Overflow post, but essentially they speed up SELECT queries.  The downside is they slow down INSERT/UPDATE queries and *can* use up a lot of disk space.  The MySQL manual is a good place to start reading about them:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: I have run the query and it says that it was executed correctly. So I guess their were not indexed?

Comment: Additionally are there any other tables that I should index? If yes, which ?

Comment: If your query is not any faster, then there are other issues at work. Using `EXPLAIN` is your best bet for figuring out what is happening. There's no way to tell what else you should be indexing without looking at your queries.  If you post the output from your `EXPLAIN` query as part of your question, we can probably offer more insight.

Answer (score 0):

Have you indexes on `posts.ID`, `relationships.object_ID`, `relationships.term_taxonomy_id`, `tax.term_taxonomy_id`, `tax.term_id`, `terms.term_id`, `posts.post_status`, `posts.post_author` and `tax.taxonomy` ?

Comment: Hello, I am new to this.. How can I find out and what does the INDEX will do ?

Comment: Make a [`DESCRIBE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html) query on each used table and search for `KEY` line. Indexes allow you to make faster `SELECT` queries. More on [indexes on mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)